# Issue with doctrine UUID v4 conversion in symfony app

Tags: symfony, doctrine, uuid, custom-type

Stack overflow community,

I'm facing an issue with UUID version 4 handling in my Symfony application when using Doctrine to fetch related entities from the database. Despite configuring my entities to use UUIDs as identifiers and ensuring my database supports it, I keep running into conversion problems.

**Problem description:**

After transitioning from using string identifiers to UUIDs (v4) for entity IDs, I've encountered a persistent problem where Doctrine seems to mishandle the UUID conversion, specifically when fetching related entities. The error manifests as Doctrine generating a query with UUIDs in a binary-like format (e.g., `0x546970E77A10401388351FA21F92E31A`), which doesn't match any records due to format mismatch.

The most notable impact is when attempting to use the `getEmailsTo()` method on my `EmailFormType` entity to retrieve associated `EmailTo` entities. The method returns null values, indicating no records are found, presumably due to the UUID format issue.

**Relevant code snippets:**

1. **EmailFormType entity (simplified):**

   ```php
   #[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: EmailFormTypeRepository::class)]
   #[ORM\Table(name: 'WORKSPACE_EMAIL_FORM_TYPE')]
   class EmailFormType {
       #[ORM\Id]
       #[ORM\Column(name:"id", type: UuidType::NAME, unique: true, nullable: false)]
       #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'CUSTOM')]
       #[ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class: 'doctrine.uuid_generator')]
       private Uuid $id;
       // Other properties and methods...
       /**
         * @var Collection
       */
       #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'emailFormType', targetEntity: EmailTo::class)]
       private Collection $emailsTo;
        /**
         *
         */
         public function __construct()
         {
            $this->emailsTo = new ArrayCollection();
         }
       public function getEmailsTo(): Collection
       {
        return $this->emailsTo;
       }
   }
   ```
2. **Function to fetch emails:**

   ```php
   public function getFormattedEmails(EmailFormType $emailFormType, string $type): string {
       return implode(';', $emailFormType->getEmailsTo()
           ->filter(fn(EmailTo $emailTo) => $emailTo->getType() === $type)
           ->map(fn(EmailTo $emailTo) => $emailTo->getEmail())
           ->toArray());
   }
   ```

**My field in my ORACLE database :**

ID --- VARCHAR2(100)

**Executed request:**

```
SELECT t0.id AS ID_1, t0.email AS EMAIL_2, t0.type AS TYPE_3, t0.email_form_type_id AS EMAIL_FORM_TYPE_ID_4 FROM WORKSPACE_EMAIL_TO t0 WHERE t0.email_form_type_id = 0x546970E77A10401388351FA21F92E31A;
```

Any help or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered an issue while trying to maintain a `VARCHAR2(100)` type for my entity ID field in the ORACLE database, and here's how I resolved it while ensuring proper handling of UUIDs:

1. **Creation of a Custom Type**: I created a custom field type to handle UUIDs.
2. **Configuration Update**: I added this custom type to my `doctrine.yaml` configuration.
3. **Entity Modification**: I updated my entity to utilize this custom field type.

Here's the class representing my custom field type:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Doctrine;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
use Symfony\Component\Uid\Uuid;

class CustomUuidType extends Type
{
    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform): mixed
    {
        return $value instanceof Uuid ? $value->toRfc4122() : $value;
    }

    // Ensure this method can return null for nullable fields
    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform): ?Uuid
    {
        return $value === null ? null : Uuid::fromString($value);
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return 'custom_uuid';
    }

    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $column, AbstractPlatform $platform): string
    {
        return $platform->getColumnDeclarationSQL('varchar', $column);
    }
}
```

Modification to the `doctrine.yaml` file:

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        types:
            custom_uuid: App\Doctrine\CustomUuidType
```

My entity setup:

```php
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: EmailFormTypeRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: 'WORKSPACE_EMAIL_FORM_TYPE')]
class EmailFormType
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(name:"id", type:"custom_uuid", length: 100, unique: true, nullable: false)]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'CUSTOM')]
    #[ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class: 'doctrine.uuid_generator')]
    private Uuid $id;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'emailFormType', targetEntity: EmailTo::class)]
    private Collection $emailsTo;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->emailsTo = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): Uuid
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmailsTo(): Collection
    {
        return $this->emailsTo;
    }
}
```

With these changes, Doctrine now executes queries correctly, with proper conversion handling for UUIDs:

```
SELECT t0.id AS ID_1, t0.email AS EMAIL_2, t0.type AS TYPE_3, t0.email_form_type_id AS EMAIL_FORM_TYPE_ID_4 FROM WORKSPACE_EMAIL_TO t0 WHERE t0.email_form_type_id = ?
Parameters:
[
  "546970e7-7a10-4013-8835-1fa21f92e31a"
]
```

This setup ensures that my application correctly handles UUIDs as `VARCHAR2(100)` in the database while leveraging Symfony's powerful Doctrine ORM capabilities.